# Android: How to build a Tab-flow-layout with fragment collection & listview in it?

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, android-tablelayout, fragmenttransaction, fragment-tab-host

Novice with Android! Need help to work out with the following layout of my project!
I have a tabcollection with a Actionbar. which shows

```
> tab 1 -->screen 1 (Contains a listview from json webservice, while clicking on a listview cell will pass a parameter to screen 2) -> screen 2(will be initializing with the parameter got from screen 1)

> tab 2 -->screen 3 (Contains a listview and with few textview & button, while button action will pass data to screen 4) -> screen 4 (will load data got from screen 3)

> tab 3 -->screen 5 (same as screen 3) -> screen 6 (same as screen 4)
```

Now, I have been surfing whole google with my queries, & found a thousand of examples & hundreds of way to do this layout for my application! But I have choose the following to make this work!

```
 
Took a MainActivity extending FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener (with viewpager included)
 --> have added fragments  with FragmentPagerAdapter
    1.Fragment1 (contains a listview with OnItemClickListener, but dont know how to pass data with FragmentTransaction 2 & load it, need help here !!)
    2.Fragment3 (same as)
    3.Fragent5 (same as)
```

But , there's another way to do this with FragmentTabHost .Which is the correct way?
Am i going to the right direction till now, or there is other ways to do these things! I have totally lost my way in the ocean of google! Someone, Help me out!! Need some good example with code (either from github or any blog, website, etc)